# Colloquial structures meanings

Tags: colloquial-language

I would like to know how many meanings have the colloquial structure "ain't" aparte from: am not, is not, are not and have not. Example, the song, ain't nobody by Felix Jaehn:

> Ain't nobody
>   Loves me better
>   Makes me happy
>   Makes me feel this way
>   Ain't nobody
>   Loves me better than you

Thank you all, indeed!

Comment: That usage in the song just means "is not".  It's a shortened version, using a double negative: **There is not anybody :: There ain't nobody :: Ain't nobody.**

Comment: Aint also means "do not"